# JFrog Xray SBOM: Why are there rpm packages with multiple versions that doesn't show up on my docker container?

Tags: docker, artifactory, rpm, jfrog-xray

Can anyone explain why sometimes in my Xray SBOM export I see versions/releases of RPM packages I never installed?
For example,
I have a ubi8-minimal image and I also have a grafana builder image where I pull in grafana.rpm and build it in my final image. The only notable thing I did to get my final image is a microdnf update and a rpm installing grafana.rpm.
In ubi8-minimal, Xray sees that there is a rpm package called audit-libs with version 3.0.7-5.el8
In my release image, Xray also sees audit-libs but there are 3 releases (3.0.7-4.el8, 3.0.7-5.el8, and 3.0.7-2.el8.2).

I checked the running container of the release image using
`rpm -qa`
and I only see release 3.0.7-5.el8 for audit-libs.

Even Docker Desktop only sees release 3.0.7-5.el8.

There were many RPM packages with this issue.

Why is this the case? It would be nice to know how Artifactory Xray exactly constructs this SBOM but I couldn't find details on that.

Comment: What version of Xray are you using?
We made some major improvements in the rpm detection area in recent versions and that might cause these false positives.
In the latest version I can confirm that ubi8-minimal only finds audit-libs 3.0.7-5.el8.

Comment: Right I do only see 3.0.7-5 for ubi8-minimal but after doing a microdnf update I see more distributions within XRay for the newly created image based off of ubi8-minimal. Also, is there a good way to see the source of where xray finds these components like docker scout and more info to identify if packages are transient dependencies?